# Why I cannot catch error outside of function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, error-handling

I'm using nodeJS for my web server.

I'm coding Database API server but want to response 404 error when there is no entry for query.

But MariaDB NodeJS Connector doesn't return error when there is no result for query, it just returns empty rows.

So I handle it with custom error. But it doesn't work well.

Here is my source code. What's the problem?

```
function sendQueryError(res, err) {
  console.log('Query error : ' + err + ' - ' + err.message + '(' + err.errno + ')')
  var error = {
    code: 400,
    message: err.message
  };

  switch (err.errno) {
    case 404:
      error.code = 404;
      error.message = 'No Entry';
      break;
    case 1062:
      error.code = 409;
      error.message = 'Already exists'
      break;
    case 1366:
      error.code = 400;
      error.message = 'Wrong value. Check following message : ' + err.message;
  }
  res.status(error.code);
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  var response = {
    success: false,
    error: {
      code: error.code,
      message: error.message
    }
  };
  res.send(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
  return;
}

async function selectDB(query, data) {
  let conn;
  var rows
  try {

    conn = await pool.getConnection();
    if (data)
      rows = await conn.query(query, data);
    else
      rows = await conn.query(query);

    if (!rows[0]) // When there is no result for query
    {
      var err = new Error('No Entry');
      err.errno = 404;
      console.log(`Error 1`);
      throw err;
    }
    console.log('Query success and return');
    var result = {
      success: true,
      data: rows
    }

  } catch (err2) {
    console.log(`Error 2`);
    throw err2;
  } finally {
    if (conn) {
      conn.end()
    }
    return result;
  }
}

app.get('/Users/:UserId', async function(req, res) {
  if (!authDB(req.header('Authorization'), res))
    return;

  if (!isNaN(req.params.UserId)) {
    try {
      var result = await selectDB('SELECT * FROM User WHERE userNum = ?', [req.params.UserId]);
      console.log(`Received result = ${result}`);
      res.send(JSON.stringify(result));
    } catch (err) // last error catch
    {
      console.log(`Error 3`);
      sendQueryError(res, err);
    }
  } else {
    try {
      var result = await selectDB('SELECT * FROM User WHERE id = ?', [req.params.UserId]);
      res.send(JSON.stringify(result));
    } catch (err) {
      sendQueryError(res, err);
    }
  }

});
```

As you can see in source code, if I query with UserID(Number), server calls the function selectDB and try to find row corresponding to userID.

When there is no result, the output I expected is "Error1 Error2 Error3".

But in real, the output is like this.

Error 1
Error 2
Received result = undefined

So I cannot understand why server doesn't call "last error catch"?

if I throw error in the function and it doesn't have catch anymore in function, it should return error to outside of function where called that function.

Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a return statement in your finally block. This `return` takes precedence over the `throw` from the catch block, hence `result` is returned, resulting in the behaviour.

You probably want to change your code to:

```
async function selectDB(query, data) {
  let conn;
  let rows;
  try {    
    conn = await pool.getConnection();
    if (data)
      rows = await conn.query(query, data);
    else
      rows = await conn.query(query);

    if (!rows || !rows[0]) // When there is no result for query
    {
      var err = new Error('No Entry');
      err.errno = 404;
      console.log(`Error 1`);
      throw err;
    }
    console.log('Query success and return');
    return {
      success: true,
      data: rows
    }

  } catch (err2) {
    console.log(`Error 2`);
    throw err2;
  } finally {
    if (conn) {
      conn.end()
    }
  }
}
```